# win32 - detecting all the parent windows of an child window

Tags: winapi, win32gui

Just like the `EnumChildWindows` API, was wondering if the opposite is possible.. i.e., if there is an technique or API to enumerate all the Parent windows of an child window, and ultimately arrive at the main application window.

My issue is that I have more than 1 different applications having the same child window (identifiable by its window class and caption). I want to detect which application specific child window is active at a time, or if both are active would like to work with any one?

For example I have 2 apps running called "XYZ" and "ABC", and both having a child window/dialog having same reg. class and caption say - "Configuration". Now I would like to get the window details of the "Configuration" dialog from say the "XYZ" application?

Hope I was able to present the problem details properly.

Thanks,

Comment: I believe a window can only have one parent.

Comment: I believe you are confusing window classes with instances.

Comment: @Ionut Hulub: yes, but is it possible to move to immediate parent from an child window, and then to the next immediate parent, and so on. Until you end up with the main application parent window. Is there any elegant way to this reverse enumeration?

Comment: @XMarshall Now you are even more confusing, because what you just said is not what you said in your question. I had posted an answer for this kind of enumeration, and then deleted it because I read your question better. Now it looks I ought to undelete it?

Comment: You should remove that `having the same child window` and replace it with `having child windows of same class`.

Comment: @Ionut Hulub:yes, would appreciate you could undelete your earlier answer. Also very sorry for the confusion. (-:

Comment: @GSerg: thanks for the suggestion. Was thinking of trying that only. Will try and get back

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`GetAncestor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633502.aspx) function.

```
GetAncestor(hWnd, GA_ROOT)
```